# How to search for a string in an arraylist

Tags: java, regex, search, arraylist

I want to search for a string in an arraylist.
My ArrayList contains:

```
ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList(); 
list.add("behold");
list.add("bend");
list.add("bet");
list.add("bear");
list.add("beat");
list.add("become");
list.add("begin");
```

Now I want to search for `"bea"` and it should return a list containing `"bear"` and `"beat"`.
How can I implement it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
 List <String> list = new ArrayList();  
           list.add("behold"); 
           list.add("bend"); 
           list.add("bet"); 
           list.add("bear"); 
           list.add("beat"); 
           list.add("become"); 
           list.add("begin");

           List <String> listClone = new ArrayList<String>(); 
           for (String string : list) {
               if(string.matches("(?i)(bea).*")){
                   listClone.add(string);
               }
           }
        System.out.println(listClone);
```

Comment: its working, but if list contains Bear, than it does not matches

Comment: Just you have to change regex, suppose you want match smal 'b' and capital 'B' both then relace "(bea).*" <=> "(b|B)(ea).*".

Comment: There is another way to make above expression case insensitive, use "(?i)(bea).*".

Answer (score 20):

Loop through your list and do a contains or startswith.

```
ArrayList<String> resList = new ArrayList<String>();
String searchString = "bea";

for (String curVal : list){
  if (curVal.contains(searchString)){
    resList.add(curVal);
  }
}
```

You can wrap that in a method. The contains checks if its in the list. You could also go for startswith.

Comment: Shouldn't **String curVal : list** read: **String curVal resList** and shouldn't you add curVal to the list only if it is NOT currently in the list?

Answer (score 17):

Nowadays, Java 8 allows for a one-line functional solution that is cleaner, faster, and a whole lot simpler than the accepted solution:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("behold");
list.add("bend");
list.add("bet");
list.add("bear");
list.add("beat");
list.add("become");
list.add("begin");

List<String> matches = list.stream().filter(it -> it.contains("bea")).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(matches); // [bear, beat]
```

And even easier in Kotlin:

```
val matches = list.filter { it.contains("bea") }
```

Comment: Stream requires Android Api level > 24.

Comment: Wrong.  It requires 24 or greater. ( >= )

Answer (score 9):

May be easier using a java.util.HashSet. For example:

```
  List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
  list.add("behold");
  list.add("bend");
  list.add("bet");

  //Load the list into a hashSet
  Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
  if (set.contains("bend"))
  {
    System.out.println("String found!");
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Since your list doesn't appear to be sorted, you have to iterate over its elements. Apply [`startsWith()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) or [`contains()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to each element, and store matches in an auxiliary list. Return the auxiliary list when done.

Answer (score 2):

Better way is to use matches() method on every String element of the array. This will help you to search any pattern through regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Order I've seen :

```
// SearchList is your List  
// TEXT is your Search Text
// SubList is your result

                    ArrayList<String> TempList = new ArrayList<String>(
                            (SearchList));
                    int temp = 0;
                    int num = 0;
                    ArrayList<String> SubList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while (temp > -1) {
                        temp = TempList.indexOf(new Object() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                                return obj.toString().startsWith(TEXT);
                            }
                        });
                        if (temp > -1) {
                         SubList.add(SearchList.get(temp + num++));
                         TempList.remove(temp);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: you can use instead of .StartsWith , .equals or .contains

Answer (score 0):

First you have to copy, from AdapterArrayList to tempsearchnewArrayList ( Add ListView items into tempsearchnewArrayList ) , because then only you can compare whether search text is appears in Arraylist or not.

After creating temporary arraylist, add below code.

```
    searchEditTextBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String txt = charSequence.toString().trim();
            int txtlength = txt.length();
            if (txtlength > 0) {
                AdapterArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                for (int j = 0; j< tempsearchnewArrayList.size(); j++) {
                    if (tempsearchnewArrayList.get(j).get("type").toLowerCase().contains(txt)) {
                        AdapterArrayList.add(tempsearchnewArrayList.get(j));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                AdapterArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                AdapterArrayList.addAll(tempsearchnewArrayList);
            }
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (AdapterArrayList.size() > 0) {
                mainactivitylistview.setAdapter(adapter1);
            } else {
                mainactivitylistview.setAdapter(null);
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List <String> list = new ArrayList();  
           list.add("behold"); 
           list.add("bend"); 
           list.add("bet"); 
           list.add("bear"); 
           list.add("beat"); 
           list.add("become"); 
           list.add("begin");

           List <String> listClone = new ArrayList<String>(); 
           Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("bea",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); //incase u r not concerned about upper/lower case
           for (String string : list) {
               if(pattern.matcher(string).find()) {
                   listClone.add(string);
                   continue;
               }
           }
        System.out.println(listClone);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Its pretty simple, i compiled a Pattern object (Pattern.compile("bea",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)) with 'bea' as my input and i wanted it to ingnore the case of searched pattern.Next i am matching this pattern with all strings in list 1 by 1 and checking if there is atleast 1 match by find() method, if there is any then i am adding matched string into a new list i.e listClone.

Answer (score 0):

TRY using Google guava library
FOR MORE INFO --> https://github.com/google/guava

```
Iterable<String> result = Iterables.filter(yourListContainStringsYouWantToSearch, Predicates.containsPattern(search));
Log.i("resultsInList", "performSearch:\n"+ Lists.newArrayList(result.iterator()));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
class ArrayLst
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
        ar.add("pulak");
        ar.add("sangeeta");
        ar.add("sumit");
System.out.println("Enter the name:");
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
String st=scan.nextLine();
for(String lst: ar)
{
if(st.contains(lst))
{
System.out.println(st+"is here!");
break;
}
else
{
System.out.println("OOps search can't find!");
break;
}
}
}
}
```